# Weird ruby process in App Engine Flexible instance

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am connecting via ssh to one of an App Engine **Flex** instances with .Net Core application running on it and get this:
[image]

Where does that ruby process(with 24% cpu usage) come from? Is it some internal google service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The running Ruby process is `/usr/sbin/google-fluentd`. This package contains the logger agent which is the basis of **Stackdriver Logging** and it is written in Ruby gem as explained in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/#getting_the_logging_agent_source_code). All in all, the Ruby process is using the CPU because the application’s logging.

As an aside, I noticed that the screenshot you uploaded contains your `account-id` and `project-id`. I strongly suggest you to re-upload the picture without this information for security and privacy reasons.